# CSS property wizard in PHP project using NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Long time reader, first time asking a question.

Most of my development work has been in .NET using Visual Studio. Recently I took over maintenance of a website built on PHP and downloaded NetBeans as an IDE.

NetBeans has a very nice CSS property wizard for HTML projects that highlights the CSS rules in use for a particular element and lets you edit the rules directly. However, this doesn't appear to be available for PHP projects, even for pure HTML files within the project. Is that correct, or am I just missing some configuration? I can't seem to find any confirmation either way in the documentation or forums. (It would be unfortunate if it didn't work... it's a really useful feature.)

Thanks,
Terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the visual CSS editing support that works with Google Chrome and the WebKit browser embedded in NetBeans, then this feature will be available for PHP projects in the upcoming NetBeans 7.4 release. See also this blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeanswebclient/entry/html5_development_with_java_ee

Hope this helps,
Petr